# How to get value from dynamically created radiobuttonlist using listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dynamic, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to create a dynamic Multiple-choice Question Quiz, where we have different categories in which there are multiple questions with their individual options. I need to store the selected option as per the user.

Below is the aspx code which I am using to bind the data:

```
<div id="contact-form">

    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-custom" tabindex="-1"
        id="text-field" name="text-field">
    <asp:ListView ID="lv_cat" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lv_cat_ItemDataBound">
        <EmptyDataTemplate></EmptyDataTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <h4 style="border: 2px solid #000; background-color: #ffd281;"><%# Eval("Cat_name") %></h4>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Cat_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cat_id") %>' hidden="true"></asp:Label>

            <asp:ListView ID="Lv_question" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Lv_question_ItemDataBound">
                <EmptyDataTemplate></EmptyDataTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="row">
                        <p style="text-align: left; font-weight: 600;"><%# Eval("Question") %></p>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Q_Id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Q_id") %>' hidden="true"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Rbl_options" runat="server" Style="text-align: left;">
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
<!-- /End Contact Form -->
<br />
<!-- Submit Button -->
<div class="btn-row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" class="btn btn-dark" runat="server" Text=" Submit"></asp:Button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the below is the aspx.cs code for binding the data.
Now I want to fetch the details submitted by the user.

```
private void getProjectdetails()
{
    try
    {
        BAL_Projects balprojects = new BAL_Projects();
        balprojects.P_id = p_id;
        ds = balprojects.get_data_By_project_Id(str);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lbl_Project.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["pname"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

protected void lv_cat_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Label cat_id = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl_Cat_id");
        balQuestions = new BAL_Questions();
        balQuestions.Cat_id = cat_id.Text;
        ds1 = balQuestions.get_data_questions_By_category_ID(str);
        ListView ListView2 = e.Item.FindControl("Lv_question") as ListView;
        if (ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ListView2.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
            ListView2.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

protected void Lv_question_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Label Q_id = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl_Q_Id");
        BAL_options bal_options = new BAL_options();

        ds = bal_options.get_options_for_Question(str, Q_id.Text.ToString());
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            RadioButtonList rbl_1 = (RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("Rbl_options");
            rbl_1.DataSource = ds;
            rbl_1.DataTextField = "answers";
            rbl_1.DataValueField = "A_id";
            rbl_1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

private void getCategorydata()
{
    try
    {
        BAL_category bal_category = new BAL_category();
        bal_category.p_id = p_id;
        ds = bal_category.get_data_category_By_Project_ID(str);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lv_cat.DataSource = ds;
            lv_cat.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

I also tried the below code:

```
    public void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            foreach (ListViewItem item in lv_cat.Items)
            {
                ListView listQ = (ListView)item.FindControl("lv_Question");

                foreach (ListViewItem item1 in listQ.Items)
                {
                    Label QID = (Label)item1.FindControl("lbl_Q_Id");

                    RadioButtonList rbl1 = (RadioButtonList)item1.FindControl("rbl_options");

                    string test = rbl1.SelectedValue.ToString();

                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically do the same as when you are binding data to the `Rbl_options` RadioButtonList in the ListView ItemDataBound. On the button click loop all the items in the ListView, locate the RadioButton within the item and use FindControl.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        //bind the datasource for the listview
        Lv_question.DataSource = source;
        Lv_question.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Lv_question_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    //use findcontrol to locate the radiobuttonlist and cast is back
    RadioButtonList rbl = e.Item.FindControl("Rbl_options") as RadioButtonList;

    //add some dummy listitems
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        rbl.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "Item " + i, Value = i.ToString() });
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //loop all the items in the listview
    foreach (var item in Lv_question.Items)
    {
        //use findcontrol again to locate the radiobuttonlist in the listview item
        RadioButtonList rbl = item.FindControl("Rbl_options") as RadioButtonList;

        //show results
        Label1.Text += rbl.SelectedValue + "<br>";
    }
}
```

The aspx to make the demo complete

```
<asp:ListView ID="Lv_question" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Lv_question_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Rbl_options" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @VDWWD i tried to implement the above but failed to achieve the expected output especially the Lv_question_ItemDataBound part. can you please elaborate what exactly are you trying to say.

Comment: Basically what i need to do is capture all the data at one button click. And since the display part is giving the desired output but unable to access the find control function due to the nested listview.

Comment: If the nested part is giving you trouble, you can stack FindControl. Or first find the parent and then the child object.

Comment: I used the suggested solution. but it doesn't give the selected value. Please find the edit code for the same.

Comment: can you kindly help me where am I going wrong? @VDWWD